# SweetAlert's image doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

It's my first question. I hope to be clear.
So, I use SweetAlert for the loading message with image, but the image doesn't appear and I don't know why...

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  swal({
    title: 'Sweet!',
    text: 'Modal with a custom image.',
    imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
    imageWidth: 400,
    imageHeight: 200,
    animation: false
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/32bd141c/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/32bd141c/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="https://www.google.com/">Visit google</a>
```

And I have just the frame of the image (as in the image):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL3ZY.png)

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    swal({
      title: "Sweet!",
      text: "Modal with a custom image.",
      imageUrl: "https://unsplash.it/400/200"
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/32bd141c/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/32bd141c/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- Check for loading jQuery before swal  check for running
- `onbeforeunload` event by adding alert('Working...');

Comment: Thank you very much it works, but not with `onbeforeunload` :(

Comment: some answer? :(

Comment: check `window.onbeforeunload` event , i don't known about your script!!!